# Lost navigation stack when I refresh second page after opening it by named route

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-getx

I created simple Flutter Web app using GetX named routes. Navigation works good, but when I go to second page and then refresh page, I can't back to home page anymore. I assume somehow app lost navgation stack.

What is good approach to do it?

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
class Second extends StatelessWidget {
  const Second({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Second page"),),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () => Get.back(),
          child: const Text('Go back'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      getPages: [
        GetPage(name: '/', page: () => const MyHomePage()),
        GetPage(name: '/second', page: () => const Second()),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Home page"),),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          child: const Text('Next Screen'),
          onPressed: () => Get.toNamed('/second'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```